# How to connect pervasive sql Database and Web Site using DSN

Tags: iis, odbc, dsn, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I am having an application that is running on IIS with Enabled 32 bit Application.
In a remote server(connection available in local machine),i have installed Pervasive SQL.
I have installed Pervasive SQL Driver in local machine and trying to connect the database "TestApplication" in Pervasive SQL.

For that I have created System DSN "DSNTEST", and tried with Windows Application.Its working fine.

But i couldnt connect to the database from Web Site.

An error occured "Error: ERROR [IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application".

Can anyone please help me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of PSQL are you using?  Is the application built using ASP.NET?

Comment: We are using PSQL 11.30.51.00, This version driver has been installed in our server. Yes, we are using ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the ASP.NET application is trying to run as a 64 bit application.  Because you're using PSQL v11, you can install the 64 bit ODBC driver which is part of the PSQL v11 64 bit client install (at http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv11.aspx).
The other option is to make sure that the ASP.NET project is built with a target of x86 rather than x64 or AnyCPU.